# Edit Worspress Author and Archive Title Tag

Tags: wordpress

I need to Edit Title Tag Archive/Category page and Author Page

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqrXx.png)

Comment: Are you using any SEO plugin? You can do it using Yoast plugin very easily.

Comment: It worked, Thank You

Answer (score 0):

you use in action after_setup_theme:

```php
add_theme_support( 'title-tag' )
```

or use in  tag title in tag head function `wp_title()`

use filter:

```php
add_filter( 'wp_title', 'test', 10, 2 );
```

you can change title site in wp-admin found at **Settings** -> **General**